# MailChimp query string syntax

Tags: httpwebrequest, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm using MailChimp to conduct a data export of the aggregate activity. The CSV files contain the web_id of the campaign, which I would like to use to obtain more detailed information about the campaign.

The MailChimp end-point I am using is search-campaigns and a mandatory parameter is query. However there's no instruction on how the query string is constructed. I have tried:

https://${dc}.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/search-members?&query=TRUE

And this works, but returns two records that aren't what I want. But when I try something like:

https://${dc}.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/search-members?&query=web_id=12345

where 12345 is the web_id I would like to query. The result returns zero records

https://${dc}.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/search-members?&query="web_id=12345"

returns zero records

https://${dc}.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/search-members?&query=["web_id":"12345"]

returns zero records

https://${dc}.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/search-members?&query="where web_id=12345"

returns zero records